# ASP.NET Core - How to assign a dictionary value to a session

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, asp.net-session

How to assign a dictionary value to a session in ASP.NET Core?

I getting an error:

> Cannot convert from Dictionary<string, bool> to string

```cs
//Role
var query2 = (from a in _db.MuRole
    select new { a.RoleName, a.RolePiority }).ToList();

var lvRole = "";
Dictionary<string, bool> dicRole = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
foreach (var item in query2)
{
    lvRole = item.RoleName;
    //bool status = function check();
    dicRole.Add(item.RoleName, false);
}

HttpContext.Session.SetString("Role", dicRole);
```

Comment: session value must be in string instead of dictionary. Instead of using dictionary, Append a string inside foreach loop with format as [name: value] using string builder and the  assign stringbuilder .toString() value inside the session. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

[`SessionExtensions.SetString(ISession, String, String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.setstring?view=aspnetcore-6.0) only supported provided `value` with `string` type only.

To store an object in Session, you need to serialize the object (To write JSON to a string or to a file).

If you install `Newtonsoft.Json` library,

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

HttpContext.Session.SetString("Role", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dicRole));
```

Or using the default [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#how-to-write-net-objects-as-json-serialize).

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

HttpContext.Session.SetString("Role", JsonSerializer.Serialize(dicRole));
```

To get the object from the session, you have to deserialize the string.